# Using older version of Node.js Express Framework

Tags: node.js, express

I am experiencing this problem with Node.js express framework 3.0:

https://github.com/visionmedia/express/issues/1187

I've been using express framework 2.0 and am in the process of updating my code to use the next 3.0 framework.  In the above link the guy said that he reverted back to version express@3.0.0beta1 instead of the express@3.0.0beta4 in which he was having problems with.  I'd like to do the same but I don't know how to specify express@3.0.0beta1 ??  Where in express do I do that?

When setting up my project and using:

```
npm install express
```

to install express framework in my project should I be specifying the version like this:

```
npm install express b1
```

any help or advice would be appreciated cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install a particular version:
`npm install <name>@<version>`

So in your case:
`npm install express@3.0.0beta1`